# Equivalent function that smooths faster

Tags: python, numpy, convolution, smoothing

I have written a function that removes single protruding pixels in a binary mask:

[image]

```
def remove_dots(mask, mode='constant', cval=0):
    patterns = [
        np.array([[1, 0, 0],
                  [1, 1, 0],
                  [1, 0, 0]]),
       
        np.array([[0, 0, 1],
                  [0, 1, 1],
                  [0, 0, 1]]),
        
        np.array([[1, 1, 1],
                  [0, 1, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0]]),
        
        np.array([[0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 1, 0],
                  [1, 1, 1]])
    ]
    
    punches = [
        np.array([[1, 0, 0],
                  [1, 0, 0],
                  [1, 0, 0]]),
        
        np.array([[0, 0, 1],
                  [0, 0, 1],
                  [0, 0, 1]]),
        
        np.array([[1, 1, 1],
                  [0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0]]),
        
        np.array([[0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0],
                  [1, 1, 1]])
    ]
    
    for y in range(mask.shape[1]-2):
        for x in range(mask.shape[0]-2):
            for i, a in enumerate(patterns):
                if np.array_equal(mask[x:x+a.shape[0], y:y+a.shape[1]], a):
                    mask[x:x+a.shape[0], y:y+a.shape[1]] = punches[i]

    return mask
```

The obvious problem is that the function does slow array comparisons. Do you know of a function that does exactly the same thing but is significantly faster?

Comment: Is this essentially a convolution? There are functions for that.

Comment: @jared. Yup. Writing an answer

Comment: Can you post the test image as an array?

Comment: A simple naive way to get a much faster code is simply to use Numba (or Cython) in this case since you operate with binary values and most convolution function does not support that (at best, they will be inefficient). With Numba, removing the `np.array_equal` and replacing it with loops might be a bit faster, and replacing dynamic arrays with hand written conditions should be even faster (at the expense of a quite long ugly code).

Comment: @jared I think I got the convolution working properly now.

Answer (score 4):

I might suggest using four 3x3 matching filters with kernels tailored to your shape. Something like [`scipy.signal.convolve2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html) should suit your needs perfectly. Replacement is non-trivial in the general case, but you can use the fact that you are only replacing the single center pixel in the output.

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

for p in patterns:
    # Use defaults mode='full', boundary='fill', fillvalue=0
    mask = (convolve2d(image, 2 * p - 1) == p.sum(None))
    image[mask] = 0
```

The reason for doing `2 * p - 1` rather than just `p` in the convolution is that you want to distinguish between actual punches and solid regions. If your pattern is zeros and ones, the following two chips return the same output:

```
0 0 1   0 0 1              1 1 1   0 0 1
0 1 1 , 0 1 1 -> 4   and   1 1 1 , 0 1 1 -> 4
0 0 1   0 0 1              1 1 1   0 0 1
```

But if you penalize invalid entries, you will get the correct result:

```
0 0 1   -1 -1  1              1 1 1   -1 -1  1
0 1 1 , -1  1  1 -> 4   and   1 1 1 , -1  1  1 -> -1
0 0 1   -1 -1  1              1 1 1   -1 -1  1
```

Comment: @heiland If this answers your question, then you should accept the answer. You do that by clicking the gray check mark next to the answer to make it a green check mark.